# Automatic slide advance (transduration) breaks with tdclock crono

Tags: beamer, tdclock

**NEED**

- I want to use `\crono` from the `tdclock` package on a slide.
- I *also* want the slide to advance after a set amount of time via `\transduration`.

**PROBLEM**

When using both `\transduration` and `\crono` on the same slide, the slide does *not* advance.

**MWE**

- `timeinterval` simply updates the clock at a small time interval (0.2)
- `resetpages=all` resets the crono time when that slide is displayed

```
\documentclass[16pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[timeinterval=0.2,resetatpages=all]{tdclock}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\transduration{1}
No crono - Advances after 1s
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\initclock % Needed for tdclock 
\transduration{1}
\cronominutes\pdfcolon\cronoseconds \\
Does not advance
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```